# python azure function throw exception after deployed

Tags: python, azure-functions

```
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))". See the function execution logs for additional details."
```

azure function throw above exception, any help?

Comment: you have to show us the code that produce that error

Answer (score 0):

> ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))". See the function execution logs for additional details."

The above error mentions that it will not accept any connections. So that It gives the above exception.

This issue came when the server or services were not able to reach the connection so the server can **drop** the TCP-RST connection.

Check your Function app is **UP**. In **Azure portal-> overview -> status** you can see the status of an azure function is running or not.

[image]

Check if you are trying to connect other services like (Database/storage, etc.) make sure all services are **UP**.